# How a native C++ plug-in DLL can load a private assembly located in a specific directory

Tags: assemblies, plugins, native, assembly-resolution

I have a native C++ DLL which is used as a plug-in in another application. This DLL has an embedded manifest and depends on a **private assembly located in a folder external to the application**. The application fails to load my plug-in DLL because my DLL depends on a private assembly which is never found (it is not located in the application directory, nor in the winsxs folder but in my plug-in directory whose location is not controlled by the application). The question is: how is it possible to make the system find my private assembly which is located in my own specific directory ? As an analogy, I would need an equivalent of setDllDirectory() but for assemblies. Or another way so that the system find my private assembly.

**Constraints:**

Because my DLL is a plug-in, I **cannot install anything in the directory and sub-directories of the application**. I also cannot modify the behavior of the application.
I would like to avoid sharing the assembly in winsxs.
I also have to use an assembly and not a simple DLL (that I could load with LoadLibrary) to avoid version conflicts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a global location where you could give a list of directories that form your (from java-terminology) class-path. Once you have this list just traverse the directories looking for dll's.

I have used the Registry in windows for this. An environment variable or the /etc folder under linux would also do.

This is how linkers do it, and this is one way that the .NET GAC does (it specifies a list of directories in a registry key).

-- edit 1 --

Your problem seems quite a uncomfortable mix, it's like trying to eat with a straight jacket on :P. Why don't you drop the assembly requirement and have a function in a native DLL that returns a version identifier (name-version), and then have some application logic to determine if it may use the DLL.

For example file-name (fn) = monkey-1-1 and a function call returns a struct:

```
struct version-id
{
   const char * name;
   int major_number;
   int minor_number;
};
```

Then fn monkey-1-2 would not conflict on file-name or internal conversioning. and your programming conventions or application logic would make sure no adverse collisions occur.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Without entering details, I have other constraints which imposes the use of an assembly/manifest so I cannot use simple DLLs. If I could have done it, I would have simply given a unique name to the DLLs of the assembly to avoid any conflict with the application itself or the other plug-ins and load them with LoadLibrary(). But I wanted to know if it was possible to get this equivalent of SetDllDirectory(). It seems also possible with the event AssemblyResolve to control how assemblies are loaded but it's only for managed code and not native C++...